# Each parameter in the deserialization constructor must bind to an object property or field on deserialization

Tags: asp.net-identity-3, duende-identity-server

After implementing DCR as described by Duende I get the following error when sending post request to the DCR endpoint:

```
ail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.InvalidOperationException: Each parameter in the deserialization constructor on type 'Duende.IdentityServer.Configuration.DynamicClientRegistrationEndpoint' must bind to an object property or field on deserialization. Each parameter name must match with a property or field on the object. Fields are only considered when 'JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields' is enabled. The match can be case-insensitive.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_ConstructorParameterIncompleteBinding(Type parentType)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectWithParameterizedConstructorConverter`1.OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCoreAsObject(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[TValue](Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ContinueDeserialize[TValue](ReadBufferState& bufferState, JsonReaderState& jsonReaderState, ReadStack& readStack, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromStreamAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequestJsonExtensions.ReadFromJsonAsync(HttpRequest request, Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.<HandleRequestBodyAndCompileRequestDelegateForJson>g__TryReadBodyAsync|90_0(HttpContext httpContext, Type bodyType, String parameterTypeName, String parameterName, Boolean allowEmptyRequestBody, Boolean throwOnBadRequest)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.<>c__DisplayClass90_2.<<HandleRequestBodyAndCompileRequestDelegateForJson>b__2>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IdentityServerOptions options, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession userSession, IEventService events, IIssuerNameService issuerNameService, ISessionCoordinationService sessionCoordinationService) in /_/src/IdentityServer/Hosting/IdentityServerMiddleware.cs:line 120
   at Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.MutualTlsEndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes) in /_/src/IdentityServer/Hosting/MutualTlsEndpointMiddleware.cs:line 95
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.DynamicProviders.DynamicSchemeAuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in /_/src/IdentityServer/Hosting/DynamicProviders/DynamicSchemes/DynamicSchemeAuthenticationMiddleware.cs:line 50
   at Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in /_/src/IdentityServer/Hosting/BaseUrlMiddleware.cs:line 27
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.<Invoke>g__Awaited|8_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
```

The code that I added in my class for the web application was:

`app.MapDynamicClientRegistration();`

The Json I provided the endpoint

```
{
    "redirect_uris": ["https://localhost:7067/"],
    "grant_types": ["authorization_code"],
    "client_name": "Auto Created Test Client",
    "post_logout_redirect_uris": ["https://localhost:7067/"],
    "allowed_cors_origins":["https://localhost:7067/"],
    "access_token_type": "Jwt",
    "scope": "openid",
    "identity_token_lifetime": 3600,
    "access_token_lifetime": 3600,
    "authorization_code_lifetime": 3600,
    "sliding_refresh_token_lifetime": 3600,
    "refresh_token_expiration": 3600,
    "refresh_token_usage": "ReUse",
    "update_access_token_claims_on_refresh": true,
    "require_consent": false,
    "allow_remember_consent": true,
    "consent_lifetime": 3600,
    "require_client_secret": false,
    "enable_local_login": false,
    "identity_provider_restrictions": [],
    "Extensions": [{"key":"TestExtension", "key2":"Test"}]
}
```

Tried various parameters in the body to see if it had any effect but still kept getting the same error. The Json provided was the largest set of properties but I varied with the properties.